# Need equivalent rewrite rule for Jetty as like .htaccess in httpd

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty

Am configuring Jetty server (Programmatic way) which need some URL rewrite rule as like as below

**.htaccess congiguration**

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

I need the same equivalent rewrite rule for Jetty